# Manage belongs_to relation in Rails from the opposite side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

To illustrate the question, let's say I have the following models in Rails:

```rb
class Shelf < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shelf, optional: true
end
```

In the `views/books/edit`, a user can select a `shelf` for the current book.

But the other way around is also possible. From within `views/shelves/edit`, the selected books can be assigned using a multi-select box.

Currently, I send a `params[:book_ids]` to the shelves controller where the following method takes care of the sync:

```rb
def update_books_relation
  Book.where(id: params[:book_ids])
    .update_all(shelf_id: @shelf.id)
  Book.where(shelf_id: @shelf.id)
    .where.not(id: params[:book_ids])
    .update_all(shelf_id: nil)
end
```

So, first all selected books are associated with the shelf. Then, all books that were associated before, but not selected are removed from the shelf.

This works, but I was wondering if there is an easier/more concise way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the order, first setting all the books on the shelf to nil, then setting the selected book to the shelf.  Also you can use the `books` association on the `shelf` object.

```
def update_books_relation
  @shelf.books.update_all(shelf_id: nil)
  Book.where(id: params[:book_ids]).update_all(shelf_id: @shelf.id)
end
```